# Random sum with summands not iid

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Let $X_i$ be a sequence of iid random variables, with de density function $f_X(x)=\mathrm{e}^{-x}$. Further, we have a uniform Poisson process $N(t)$ with an intensity $\lambda=2$, and hitting times $T_i$. The question is to calculate the expectation of $\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)} (X_i+T_i)^2$.

I know that for the uniform poisson process, the expectation of such a sum can be easily calculated if the summands are iid, which is here not the case, since $T_i$ is Gamma distributed with $\alpha=i$ and $\beta=\lambda$. Howewer, I also know that $T_i=W_1+...+W_i$, where $W$ is iid and exponentially distributed with mean $\lambda=2$.

I would appreciate any hints and ideas how to approach this problem.

Comment: To clarify the hitting times $T_i$ are the hitting times of the Poisson process, right? I.e. $T_i = \inf\left\{t\geq 0 : N(t) = i\right\}$

Comment: Some independence assumptions would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, @Shiva, yes, exactly.

Comment: I don't know much about the indepencdence assumptions from the question itself, but I suppose that the sequence $X_i$ is independent of both the Poisson process $N(t)$ and the hitting times $T_i$. @Michael

Comment: Assuming that independence, you can reduce it to a question that does not involve $X_i$ by expanding on $$E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)}(X_i+T_i)^2\right]=E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)}(X_i^2+2X_iT_i+T_i^2)\right]$$ Then you can use the fact that, given $N(t)=n$, the $n$ Poisson points are independently and uniformly distributed over $[0,t]$.